# Proper way to manage fixtures in django

Tags: django, fixtures, django-fixtures

today I had a discussion with my colleguaes about how we should manage fixtures in our django application. We cound not find any solution that would satisfy everyone, so I'm asking this question here.

Suppose we have quite big django project with **dozen of applications** inside, each application has tests.py file with several TestClasses. Having this, how I should manage test data for all of these applications?
From my perpective, there is 2 different ways:

1. Store all data in separate for each application **test_data.json** file. This file will contain test data for all models defined in the application's **models.py** file, irrespective of where this data is used (it can be used in tests from different application)
2. Store some common data that would be probably required by all tests (like **auth.users**) in test_data.json and data for each **TestCase** in a separate **test_case.json** file.

From my perpective, second approach seems to be more cleaner, but I would like to know if somebody could tell me the concrete pros and cons of these approaches or may be suggest some other approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about the cleanest way to define test data for your tests, I would like to recommend you read about [django-any application](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-any):

> django-any the explicit replacement for old-style, big and error-prone
>   implicit fixture files.
>
> django-any allows to specify only fields important for test, and fill
>   rest by random with acceptable values.
>
> It makes tests clean and easy to undestood, without reading fixture
>   files.
>
> ```
> from django_any import any_model, WithTestDataSeed
>
> class TestMyShop(TestCase):
>     def test_order_updates_user_account(self):
>         account = any_model(Account, amount=25, user__is_active=True)
>         order = any_model(Order, user=account.user, amount=10)
>         order.proceed()
>
>         account = Account.objects.get(pk=account.pk)
>         self.assertEquals(15, account.amount)
> ```
>
> The same approach available for forms also (django_any.any_form)

This solution is helpful for avoiding to keep extra data in you DB while your tests are executing.

Comment: Also check out factory-based test data generation with associations. https://github.com/dnerdy/factory_boy

Comment: Actually, after some problems with `django-any` I started to use exactly `factory_boy` application :)